# Why is Yiddish keyboard layout not shipped with Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xkb, hebrew

Yiddish is a Germanic language written with a modified Hebrew alphabet. There is a keyboard layout specifically for it https://github.com/nevillepark/yiddish-keys-linux - which requires a skill to configure instead of simply choosing a keyboard layout in a list. Why is it not shipped with Ubuntu? How to push it to be shipped?

Comment: Because no one has done the work on packaging it and submitting it to Debian or Ubuntu repositories, presumably. You're welcome to do it.

Comment: Yes, thank you!